# Вывод времени в Godot

Tags: вывод, godot

Вопрос по движку **Godot Engine**, а именно по **GDScript** или с использованием **других языков**.

Как я могу **вывести время** с моего устройства?

К примеру: сейчас на моём устройстве "13:17" и программа должна считать данную строку и записать в переменную.

Answer (score 0):

```
OS.get_time ( bool utc=false )
```

возвращает словарь